# Angular 8 - Dynamically insert a button with callback call on word occurrence

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to insert a button with a configurable callback dynamically by parsing a text which needs to be shown on screen.

What I want to do is to parse the text and, whenever I find a certain word occurrence (like, for example, a sort-of-tag `[innerc][/innerc]`) put instead a button with an onClick calling the provided callback.

Now, given the fact that this text is **not** written by the user at all, I am thinking of using `innerHTML` property and a pipe to parse the text by Regex expressions.

Something like:

```
<p [innerHTML]="value | putCallback : callOnClick"></p>
```

And the pipe parsing everything and putting buttons where needed.. something like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'putCallback'})
export class PutCallbackPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, callback: (val: string) => void): string {
    if (value.indexOf('[innerc]') != -1) {
      ... Parse the string, put buttons with regex and so on, then return... 
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Since this solution doesn't look that clean to me, I wanted to ask.. Is there a better option of doing this, without using `innerHTML`?

Comment: You could probably parse it, but you cannot use angular components or functionality in there..  Where does the html come from?

Comment: Do you mean, the value? Basically I have a list of paragraphs of text which I want to render.. each Paragraph can contain special tags which needs to render not as text.. But as something more.. Like buttons with callbacks and so on.

Comment: Right, so the problem is, whatever you render through innerHtml is not angular capable html.. if you know what I mean..

Comment: Yeah that's what I don't like of my solution. I would need to use a callback and then force a check of the component I want.. which is not great. That's why I was searching a more clean solution